# C# set charset on webpage

Tags: c#, parsing, character-encoding

I need set charset in GUI App.

Application getting result of parsing web page and display result in TextBox;

Web Page Charset - Windows-1251.

My display showing black rhombus.

Thx!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1{
public partial class Form1 : Form{
    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void get_field_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        string url = url_field.Text;
        string pattern = pattern_field.Text;
        string html = string.Empty;

        HttpWebRequest  myHttpWebRequest  = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader result = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
        html = result.ReadToEnd();

        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(html, pattern);

        foreach(Match title in matches){
            GroupCollection group = title.Groups;
            result_field.Text += group[1].ToString() + "\n\n\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... You need to elaborate on your particular problem. I for one cannot understand what it is you're asking for.

Comment: Still not clear what it is you are asking for.

Comment: What I see here: You're reading data (html?) from an Url in windows 1251 encoding. Then you apply a regex on the data. Then you concatenate the matches to a Text property of a control (textbox?). You say you need to "set the charset in GUI app" since you're getting a black rhombus. This is STILL not enough information for us to solve your problem.

UTF8 is default charset in .NET. You might need to convert windows-1251 to UTF-8. I don't know since there isn't enough information to go on.

Comment: Not related to the charset issue, but for downloading the content, you can make things simpler by just using WebClient.DownloadingString - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx

Comment: also, the 'better' way to get the value of a regex group is using group[1].Value (although as you can tell, the ToString returns that)

Comment: Can you tell us exactly which characters are displaying as the black rhombus?  Can you show a screen shot (upload to imgur.com or whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

On your windows form, use a rich-textbox.

Answer (score 0):

There's not quite enough information (AFAICT) to definitively determine what is the 'real problem', but in case it's helpful, culture info is stored on a per-thread basis and you can find out the code pages used by the current thread with System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.textinfo.aspx .  You can set the CurrentUICulture to something else if needed.

Knowing the exact character(s) that are failing to display would be much more helpful, though. :)  In my experience all utf8 strings displayed fine as long as I had the right font(s) installed (although I don't remember if that meant installing a Language Pack into Windows or not)